# pandas groupby and widen dataframe with ordered columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot

I have a long form dataframe that contains multiple samples and time points for each subject. The number of samples and timepoint can vary, and the days between time points can also vary:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({"subject_id":[1,1,1,2,2,3],
                    "sample":["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"],
                    "timepoint":[19,11,8,6,2,12],
                    "time_order":[3,2,1,2,1,1]
 })

   subject_id   sample  timepoint   time_order
0    1            A        19           3
1    1            B        11           2
2    1            C         8           1
3    2            D         6           2
4    2            E         2           1
5    3            F        12           1
```

I need to figure out a way to generalize grouping this dataframe by subject_id and putting all samples and time points on the same row, in time order.

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

```
    subject_id  sample1 timepoint1  sample2   timepoint2  sample3 timepoint3
0    1            C         8         B        11        A      19                              
1    2            E         2         D         6       null   null         
5    3            F        12        null      null     null   null
```

Pivot gets me close, but I'm stuck on how to proceed from there:

```
test_df = test_df.pivot(index=['subject_id', 'sample'],
columns='time_order', values='timepoint')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for pivoting, sorting MultiIndex in columns, flatten it and last convert `subject_id` to column:

```
df = (test_df.set_index(['subject_id', 'time_order'])
             .unstack()
             .sort_index(level=[1,0], axis=1))
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}{x[1]}')
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   subject_id sample1  timepoint1 sample2  timepoint2 sample3  timepoint3
0           1       C         8.0       B        11.0       A        19.0
1           2       E         2.0       D         6.0     NaN         NaN
2           3       F        12.0     NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a=test_df.iloc[:,:3].groupby('subject_id').last().add_suffix('1')
b=test_df.iloc[:,:3].groupby('subject_id').nth(-2).add_suffix('2')
c=test_df.iloc[:,:3].groupby('subject_id').nth(-3).add_suffix('3')
pd.concat([a, b,c], axis=1)

    

            sample1  timepoint1 sample2  timepoint2 sample3  timepoint3
subject_id                                                            
1                C           8       B        11.0       A        19.0
2                E           2       D         6.0     NaN         NaN
3                F          12     NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN
```